# How can I sum a column based on like?

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join, sql-like

I have a SQL table `AddressCount` that has 3 fields: `address`, `state`, and `numEntities`. What I want to do is get the sum of numEntities for each address + state combination based on a like. This is somewhat hard to describe, but I think the following correlated query represents correctly what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT Address, State, 
    (SELECT SUM(NumEntities)
    FROM AddressCount innerQry 
    WHERE innerQry.address LIKE '%' + outerQry.address + '%' 
        AND innerQry.state = outerQry.state) As NumEntities
FROM AddressCount outerQry
```

Basically, I want to end up with a table that has an address, a state, and the sum of numEntities for all addresses like that address surrounded by wildcards. So, if the address is "25 Courtland Rd" and the state is NJ, I want to get the sum of numEntities for all rows that have a state of NJ and an address like '%25 Courtland Rd%'. I'd love to be able to accomplish this with a GROUP BY LIKE, but I don't think this is possible with SQL. The basic concept is to accomplish something like this:

```
SELECT address, state, sum(numEntities)
FROM AddressCount
GROUP BY (LIKE '%' + address + '%')
```

The correlated query sql statement I posted above seems accurate, but I'd like to accomplish the same thing, if possible, by an inner join of the table on itself. I recently read that it's possible to join tables on a LIKE expression, so I want to accomplish something like the following:

```
SELECT t1.Address, t1.State, SUM(t2.NumEntities)
FROM AddressCount t1
INNER JOIN AddressCount t2
    ON t1.state = t2.state
    AND t2.address LIKE '%' + t1.address + '%'
```

This doesn't seem to work, though... any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, adding `GROUP BY t1.state, t1.address` should work.

Comment: I don't want to group by the exact address, I want to group by anything LIKE that address...

Comment: I think that is what happens here, at least what I imagined you meant (and @Jacek as well, apparently :) ). Could you give some examples of addresses you would consider belonging in the same group?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what happens here: if you have those three rows, all in state NJ and with numEntities 1, 2 and 4 respectively, you will get a result row: `25 Courtland Road - NJ - 7`. I think if you use a left join instead of inner, you will also get: `25 Courtland Road Apt. 34 - NJ - 0` and `West 25 Courtland Road - NJ - 0`.

Comment: Unless of course, you just tried this and something different happens, in which case I'd like to know what the result is :)

Comment: Thanks, sorry for misunderstanding, I'm having a hard time getting my head around this query... This seems to be working so far :) although it takes forever :(

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add

```
GROUP BY t1.Address, t1.State
```

...at the end of your second query. Just did a quick test with PostgreSQL and combining LIKE and GROUP BY works as expected, so i see no reason it schouldn't in your case.

Comment: I don't want to group by the exact address, I want to group by anything LIKE that address...

Comment: But you don't group by exact t2.address - only by exact t1.address, which is exact by your definition already.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:
SELECT x.state, x.address, SUM(x.NumEntities)
FROM (SELECT * FROM AddressCount WHERE address LIKE %) x
GROUP BY x.state

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one?

```
SELECT a.Address,t.State,t.numEntities
FROM
  dbo.AddressCount a,
        (SELECT     State,SUM([Count]) as numEntities
        FROM dbo.AddressCount
        WHERE Address LIKE '%+address+%' 
        GROUP BY State ) t
WHERE a.State = t.State
```